# What is the maximum size of an ellipse in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, system.drawing

I am attempting to use a `System.Drawing.Graphics` object to draw an ellipse (really a circle) that is very large (millions of pixels, though since the picture box I'm drawing into is reasonably sized I ought to get either no image or something approaching a line, depending on the ellipse's location). I am using System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pen, RectangleF) to draw the ellipse. I can successfully construct a RectangleF describing the dimensions I want. For example, this `ToString`'d `RectangleF` describes an ellipse that is much bigger than my actual visible view space, and when passed to DrawElipse should actually do nothing (since no part of the edge of the elipse intersects the visible region):

```
{X=-9.065709E+08,Y=-9.065711E+08,Width=1.813143E+09,Height=1.813143E+09}
```

Instead, trying to draw an ellipse bounded by that `RectangleF` is producing a `OverflowException`. The `DrawElipse` method is not specified to ever throw an `OverflowException`, nor does the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd0737f9.aspx) give any indication that some `RectangleF`s are inappropriate arguments.

How big of an ellipse can I draw, and how far away from 0 can its center be, before `DrawElipse` breaks?

Comment: You do realize that you are trying to draw something that requires insanely huge amount of memory? Your Graphics probably was created form image. 32bit bitmap with size of about 20000 x 30000 pixels requires more than 2GB of memory. And that's just a tiny portion of what you are trying to draw.

Comment: Ideally, drawing anything in a picture box of a certain size should not take more memory than is required to store the image displayed in the picture box. I would expect the out-of-bounds portions of the ellipse to not be drawn anywhere.